# Base Class Generic Arguments Clarification

Tags: c#

I have an Abstract class that is implemented like this:

```
public abstract class BaseImplementation<T, U> : IHistory<T>
        where T : class, IEntity, new()
        where U : DbContext, new()
```

I understand that the generic argument `<U>` is an EF `DbContext`.
I understand that the generic argument `<T>` must be a class that implements the `IEntity` Interface.

What is the  `"new()"?` Must be a new instance of a given class? What is the purpose of that? 
Note that is declared in both `<T>` and `<U>`

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new()` is a constraint specifying that the type argument must have a **public parameterless constructor**. For more information about the generic type constraint, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)。

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx):

"The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract."

I don't really have much more to add to this as I think the explanation above is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

The `new()` is called a [new constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) and it requires that the type argument has a public, parameterless constructor.

The benefit of using it is that you can create an instance of your generic type inside the class, without explicitly knowing the type passed in.

For example:

```
public PersonEntity : IEntity
{
    // public parameterless constructor
    public PersonEntity()
    {
    }
}

public abstract class BaseImplementation<T, U> : IHistory<T>
    where T : class, IEntity, new()
    where U : DbContext, new()
{
    public T CreateEntity() 
    {
        var entity = new T();  
        // entity will be the type passed to `T` when instantiating `BaseImplementation`
    }
}
```

Then usage would be something like:

```
public class PersonImpl : BaseImplementation<PersonEntity, DataContext>
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        var entity = CreateEntity();
        // entity is typeof(PersonEntity);
    }
}
```